# how to define a array m by n with elements which are function of some factors

Tags: c++

I try to write code for this kind of problem like below;

this is part of code and I already define the function.
I want in this loop M[i][j] calculate based on function and allocate to this cell

But I have this error "Expression must have a constant value"

Can anyone help me how I have to write this kind of code.

```
for (i=0;i=2;i++){
    for (j=0;i=2;j++){
        double M[i][j];
        M[i][j] = function(n,m);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Let's begin:

1) *declaring the array*

`double M[i][j];` is not declaring an array. In C/C++, the way to do declare a static array would be:

```
double M[MAX1][MAX2]; //where MAX1 and MAX2 are some constant, predefined values.
```

There is something called *variable-length array*, but for now, let's say array lengths in C/C++ must be **constants**.

To conclude:

```
int max = 100;
[...]
double Array[max]; ---- WRONG

#define MAX 100
[...]
double Array[MAX]; ---- RIGHT
```

Same thing applies for multidimensional arrays.

Also, you should do this before the `for` loops - declaring an array in every iteration makes no sense.

2) *assigning values*

```
int n=5, m=5; //for example
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
 for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
 {
   M[i][j]=someFunction(n,m);
 }
```

This will assign the value of `function(n,m)` to every element of your `n`x`m` array.
I guess this is what you had in mind.

You might want to read a good C/C++ book. These are really basic things. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `M[][]` outside of that loop it seems.

```
double M[2][2];
for (i=0;i=2;i++)
{
    for (j=0;i=2;j++)
    {
        M[i][j] = function(n,m);
    }
}
```

Brackets added for clarity.

Does the function modify `m` and `n`? If not, then at the moment you'll populate every item in the array with the same value.